# Google Charts table sorting via keyboard

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-visualization, accessibility

I'm trying to use the Google Charts API on a website that must be 100% Section 508 compliant, i.e., accessible to those with disabilities.

Google Charts tables have a 'sort' function but in its default state column headers cannot be selected by the keyboard for sorting.

I can use some Javascript to inject "tabindex=0" attributes into the column header elements easily enough, and as expected, that makes the column headers focusable...but surprisingly, clicking on the enter key does nothing. Same thing happens if I make the sort arrows inside the column headers focusable - I can focus on it using TAB, but I still can't select it.

Does anyone have a solution for this? If there is no straightforward way to create a table that's sortable using only the keyboard, is there a workaround to transform a focus/keypress into an onclick?

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle that uses jQuery to redraw the chart on a keypress:

http://jsfiddle.net/mVYeL/

Here's the relevant code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    'packages': ['table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

var table;
var data;
var options = {sortAscending:true};

function sortTable(col) {
    if (options.sortColumn == col) {
        options.sortAscending = !options.sortAscending;
    } else {
        options.sortAscending = true;
    }
    options.sortColumn = col;
    table.draw(data, options);
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==49) { sortTable(0); }
    if (e.keyCode==50) { sortTable(1); }
    if (e.keyCode==51) { sortTable(2); }
});

function drawStuff() {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    table.draw(data, options);
};
```

Comment: This is a good start. I would recommend changing `keydown` to listen to <kbd>enter</kbd>, figure out the table and column, set a flag, sort the col ASC. Then you can unset the flag for DESC. Also most Assistive Tech uses 1-6 to navigate H1-H6, so either this won't work or, the focus would move elsewhere after the sort

Comment: Ryan is absolutely right - screen readers will already have assigned uses for 1-3 and users will expect to use the Enter button to trigger a focused element. Still, Jeremy's original comment gives me a rough sketch to address the problem and Ryan provided a good roadmap to implement it, so thank you both. Once I've got a working snippet I'll add it as a comment for future reference.